# Setting a Environment Variables via Powershell for another User

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

I am trying to set the environment variables of a user XYZ from the powershell of admin user ABC. I am using Start-Process to launch the powershell of user XYZ but i am not able to capture the output. All this process needs to be done in Java.

Can someone help me out.

Thanks 
Ajax

Answer (score 0):

When you change environment variables, the change affects only the current PowerShell session (like if you were using SET command in a Windows cmd). To make the changes permanent, you have to change them with a utility like [SETX](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html). You must also have permission to change the values.

Comment: Hi David, 
Thanks for the answer. I tried using SETX but the disadvantage with SETX is that we need to provide the username and password(plain text format)

Comment: Hi David,
To give you more idea of what I am trying to do is as follows.
I am logged on to system as User- ABC and I wish to add environemnt variables to User - XYZ which is on the same system. This process has to be secure and has to be done via Java code .
In SetX or Runas u need to give a password which is plain-text so security is lost.

Comment: Don't know what having java in the picture adds as a constraint, but maybe you can find something for you here: http://learningpcs.blogspot.com/2012/01/powershell-v2-permanently-add.html

Answer (score -2):

Check this TechNet article on it: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730964.aspx

Basically, you're going to want to set it using the .NET method at the machine scope:

`[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("TestVariable","Test Value","Machine")`

You'll need to restart your Powershell session to be able to access the new environment variable after creating it.

Comment: the article is absolutely useless, because does not cover this question of how to set env vars for ANOTHER USER