# Access a specific user environment variable on windows server

Tags: windows, powershell, environment-variables

Is there a way to access to a specific user environment variable using Powershell ?

On the server machine, we have 50 users.
I want to know if a specific user for example `user1` is using a different value for the environment variable `PYTH_HOME_LOG`.

This System variable points to `C:\PYTHON\LOG`, I want to check which user changed this location by configuring a user environment variable `PYTH_HOME_LOG`.

Comment: I think the answer here will point you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737401/setting-a-environment-variables-via-powershell-for-another-user

Comment: @gvee : this allow you to set your environment as system or user, but not to access other user environment variable.

Comment: You posted an answer (since deleted) saying that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54026754/205580) by Mathias solved your problem. If so, please update your question to indicate that you only want to check users with a loaded profile (ntuser.dat), either from an active logon or lingering (temporarily) from a previous logon.

Answer (score 4):

If you are a member of the local Administrators group you can simply go through all the user registry hives and search for the `Environment` variables there:

```
$AllUserHives = Get-ChildItem Registry::HKEY_USERS\ |Where Name -like "HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21*[0-9]"
foreach($UserHive in $AllUserHives){
  if(Get-ItemProperty -Path "$UserHive\Environment" -Name PYTH_HOME_LOG -EA SilentlyContinue){
    # User is overriding %PYTH_HOME_LOG%
  }
}
```

You can grab the corresponding user name either from the `Volatile Environment` registry subtree by searching for the `USERNAME` env variable, or you can use [`IdentityReference.Translate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.identityreference.translate):

```
$SID = [System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]"S-1-5-21-436246-18267386-368368356-356777"
$Username = $SID.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value
```

or, in this case:

```
$SID = ($UserHive -split '\\')[-1] -as [System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]
$Username = $SID.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value
```

Comment: You're not loading the user profile, so this only checks accounts that are logged on with the profile loaded.

Comment: "\Registry\User" (predefined handle `HKEY_USERS`) is a dynamic key where user profile hives are loaded (e.g. "%USERPROFILE%\NTUSER.DAT" and "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\UsrClass.dat"). The profile gets loaded via `LoadUserProfile`, which makes an RPC to the User Profile service. The caller must have the backup and restore admin privileges. The service gets the account's SID string and looks up the "ProfileImagePath" in "Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList" relative to "\Registry\Machine" (predefined handle `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`), and loads the keys via `NtLoadKeyEx`.